# Editing page numbers

Tags: xetex, page-numbering, report

How can I make the page numbers begin from 2, and hide them in the first two pages in LaTeX document which is using the report class.

Comment: Use `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\setcounter{page}{2}`.

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{2}` works, but when I add  `\pagestyle{empty}` to the page I want without numbers numbering disappears from random pages

Comment: I would use \thispagestyle{empty} on the first two pages where you want no page numbers.  If you also leave the counter alone, then it should begin as 3 on page 3

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me :

```
\documentclass{report}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{noNumberPage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{3}

...
```